# Construct a query to filter many-to-many for all B instances related to a given A instance

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get all `TableB` instances that are related to a specific `TableA` instance.  It is a many-to-many relationship.  How do I construct this query?

```
class TableA(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tableA'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class TableB(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tableB'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    many_to_many = db.relationship(TableA, secondary='association_table')

association_table = db.Table('association',
    db.Column('tableA_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(TableA.id)),
    db.Column('tableB_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(TableB.id))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the relationship's [`contains`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.contains) method to filter TableB items that are related to the TableA item.

```
session.query(TableB).filter(TableB.many_to_many.contains(eleA))
```

Or use [`any`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.any) to perform more complex filters on the relationship.

```
# for example, all B's related to A's with id < 10
session.query(TableB).filter(TableB.many_to_many.any(TableA.id < 10))
```

Or if performance over a very large set of data is a concern, use `join` and `filter`.

```
 session.query(TableB).join(TableB.many_to_many).filter(TableA.id == eleA.id)
```