# How can I create a SQLAlchemy query containing only instances related to a specific instance of a model?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, introspection

I am given an instance of a SQLAlchemy model `instance` and the name of a relationship `relation` on that instance. I can access all related instances by doing `getattr(instance, relation)`. How can I construct a *query* that contains all instances of that relationship, or in other words, a query that evaluates to `getattr(instance, relation)`? I am given no other information about the database tables, etc.

This is similar to the question [Construct a query to filter many-to-many for all B instances related to a given A instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31839150/108197), but I don't have the table definitions.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was as follows. Assume `instance` is an instance of a model, `relation` is a string representing the relationship attribute of that model, `'id'` is the primary key for the related model, and `related_model` is the related model. This solution filters the related model by only those instances whose primary key is in the list of known primary keys from the given instance's to-many relationship attribute:

```
relationship = getattr(instance, relation)
primary_keys = {getattr(inst, 'id') for inst in relationship}
query = session.query(related_model)
query.filter(getattr(related_model, 'id') in primary_keys)
```